# How to setup radiobutton using angularjs?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

This is my use case

In my HTML page, I have two sets of radio buttons: Labeled: "PRESENT" and "ABSENT" / Values: True and False respectively.

Intially i want to set status as "PRESENT" in all companies.

If i set ABSENT radio button in header of the table it will update status as ABSENT in all companies and also work in individual too

This is my script

```
<script>
     var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

     myApp.controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {

            $scope.companies = [{
                "id": 4,
                "name": "Facebook"
            }, {
                "id": 3,
                "name": "Twitter"
            }, {
                "id": 2,
                "name": "Google"
            }, {
                "id": 1,
                "name": "Apple"
            }]

            $scope.userChoice = {};

     }]);

</script>
```

My html page is

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>#</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th><input type="radio" ng-model="allPresent" name="company" value="{{company.id}}" />Present</th>
            <th><input type="radio" ng-model="allAbsent" name="company" value="{{company.id}}" />Absent</th>
        </tr>   
        <tr ng-repeat="company in companies">
            <td>{{$index+1}}</td>
            <td>{{company.name}}</td>
            <td><input type="radio" ng-model="userChoice.companyIdPresent" name="companyId" value="{{company.id}}" /></td>
            <td><input type="radio" ng-model="userChoice.companyIdAbsent" name="companyId" value="{{company.id}}" /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>CompanyId is: {{userChoice.companyId}}
    <br>
    <br>
    <button ng-disabled="!userChoice.companyId">Continue</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Intially i want to set status as PRESENT in all companies

My Expected output is

```
$scope.userChoice = [{
                "companyId": 4,
                "status": "PRESENT"
            }, {
                "id": 3,
                "status": "ABSENT"
            }, {
                "id": 2,
                "status": "ABSENT"
            }, {
                "id": 1,
                "status": "PRESENT"
            }]
```

can you help me to setup this scenario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code there several issues

- Radio buttons *group* should use same `ng-model`. When `ng-model` value equals to `name` value, this radio button will be selected. So your 1st pair `Present` and `Absent` have `ng-model` - `$scope.all` where default value is `'allPresent'`
- About ng-repeat: we have 4 groups, 2 in each group. So we need to create 4 different `ng-model`s. So we wrote: `ng-model="company.selected"` where `selected` value will be `true` or `false`. For that reason we defined in `ng-value` `true` and `false`
- to un/select all radios we used `ng-change="onSelect(false)"` and `ng-change="onSelect(true)"` that will run on all groups and change `selected` from/to true/false

---

So I posted working example.

*HTML*

```
<table>
        <tr>
            <th>#</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th><input type="radio" ng-model="all" name="all" value="allPresent"  ng-change="onSelect(true)" />Present</th>
            <th><input type="radio" ng-model="all" name="all" value="allAbsent"   ng-change="onSelect(false)"/>Absent</th>
        </tr>   
        <tr ng-repeat="company in companies">
            <td>{{$index+1}}</td>
            <td>{{company.name}}</td>
            <td><input type="radio" ng-model="company.selected" name="{{company.name}}" ng-value="true" /></td>
            <td><input type="radio" ng-model="company.selected" name="{{company.name}}" ng-value="false" /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

*JS*

```
$scope.companies = [{
            "id": 4,
            "name": "Facebook",
            "selected": true
        }, {
            "id": 3,
            "name": "Twitter",
            "selected": true
        }, {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "Google",
            "selected": true
        }, {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Apple",
            "selected": true
        }];

        $scope.userChoice = {}; 

        $scope.all = 'allPresent';

        $scope.onSelect = function(val){             
           angular.forEach($scope.companies, function(value){ 
               value.selected = val; 
           })
        }
```

<kbd>[DEMO FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/re4vbj7w/)</kbd>

Comment: after selecting present and absent then select header present or absent it will not work?

Comment: @AravKT pleas echeck again, I uploaded new demo

Comment: @MaximShoustin Instead of just fixing the errors, could you explain *how* and *why* your code works ; so it could be useful for further readers?